# gerrit push not working

Tags: 12.04, repository, git

I tried executing the command `git push gerrit HEAD: refs/for/BR_PS_1109`

It gave the response: `fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in HEAD:`

Git remote version is also fine, as evident below:-

```
vverma@l-vverma:~/git_repo/nextag$ git remote -v
gerrit  ssh://vverma@gerrit.corp.nextag.com:29418/apps/nextag (fetch)
gerrit  ssh://vverma@gerrit.corp.nextag.com:29418/apps/nextag (push)
origin  git@ind-git.corp.nextag.com:apps/nextag (fetch)
origin  git@ind-git.corp.nextag.com:apps/nextag (push)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space between `HEAD:` and `refs/for/BR_PS_1109` which souldn't be there. Remove the space and it should work:

> git push gerrit HEAD:refs/for/BR_PS_1109