# Error in updating the system

Tags: 12.04, apt

Whenevr i try sudo `apt-get update` in the terminal it throws the following error:-

```
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease

Err http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 111.125.139.199:8105:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease     

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg   
  Unable to connect to 111.125.139.199:8105:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 111.125.139.199:8105:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 111.125.139.199:8105:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Following problems are also arising, may be due to same issue:-

[gerrit push not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204638/gerrit-push-not-working),

[Printer Add button not enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201988/printer-add-button-not-enabled),

[apt-get install not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204602/apt-get-install-not-working),

[unable to fetch git from eclipse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204507/unable-to-fetch-git-from-eclipse),

Contents of /etc/apt/sources.list:-

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution. deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution. deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users. deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your internet connection if its working.Then just go to update center, go to  settings and uncheck sources on wich you have errors.Or check out this answer [Apt-Get Update: failure to fetch; can't connect to any sources](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135932/apt-get-update-failure-to-fetch-cant-connect-to-any-sources)

Comment: did as per your solution, it only reduced the no. of errors>>

have update dthe question with only present errors

Comment: please help on this..

Comment: @polarkatenuchie.. help please !